# Intuitive explanation of Choquet Integral for data aggregation

Tags: python, intuition, aggregation, fuzzy

I've recently stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/Fuminides/Fancy_aggregations/blob/master/Fancy_aggregations/integrals.py) python package that implements Choquet integral as a way of aggregating data. Does anyone have an intuitive way of explaining how does this integral work in this case?

Comment: Please paste in whatever context is necessary to 
understand & answer your question. We want this thread to 
remain valuable even if the link goes dead.

Comment: Well, the code contains the following refs: [Generalized
-integrals: From Choquet-like aggregation to ordered directionally monotone functions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0165011418305451?via%3Dihub) and [Multimodal fuzzy fusion for enhancing the motor-imagery-based brain computer interface](https://scholar.nycu.edu.tw/en/publications/multimodal-fuzzy-fusion-for-enhancing-the-motor-imagery-based-bra)